# How to get the start point of UIPanGesture and constantly calculate the moving distance?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

How to get the start point location of `UIPanGesture` and constantly calculate the moving distance? It would be better if you can provide some Swift code in your answer.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "catchPaned")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
func catchPaned(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    switch(gesture.state){
    case .Began:
        let touchStart = gesture.locationInView(self.view)
    case .Changed:
        let distance = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    default:
        println("default")
    }
}
```

Get start point using `locationInView`,get distance using `translationInView`

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out myself.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("panFunction:"))

myView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func panFunction(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
        let startPoint = CGPointZero
        let distance = Double(translation.y - startPoint.y)
        println("\(distance)")
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to every time `distance = Double(translation.y - startPoint.y)`,because `translation` has return the distance you want